# Gdb. Doesn't work flag -g in the assembly makefile

Tags: c++, gdb, g++

I'm want to debugging my application with gdb. I build project with makefile and here you can see the results of the project build:

Rule of compile

```
%.o : %.cpp
g++ -o $@ -c $< $(COMPILE_FLAGS) $(build_flags) $(addprefix -I , $(INCLUDE_DIRS))
```

Where

> build_flags := -O0 -g -DEBUG
>
> COMPILE_FLAGS := -Wall -MD -pipe -Wno-deprecated

Compilation and building

> mkdir -p src/. src/Object
>
> g++ -o src/./main.o -c ../../src/./main.cpp -Wall -MD -pipe -Wno-deprecated -O0 -g -DEBUG -I ../../include
>
> g++ -o src/Object/Object.o -c ../../src/Object/Object.cpp -Wall -MD -pipe -Wno-deprecated -O0 -g -DEBUG -I ../../include
>
> g++ -o ../../bin/myApp_debuq src/./main.o src/Object/Object.o -s -pipe
> make: Leaving directory `{project_name}/obj/debug'

I was removed the unnecessary and redundant information.
There you can see a lot of information about building and also you can see flag -g when source file are compiling.
After there I want to debug and I see

> (gdb) file myApp_debuq
>
> Reading symbols from {project}/bin/myApp_debuq...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
>
> (gdb) list
>
> No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.

How I know, this message telling me that there is no debug information.

Why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't strip the debug symbols from the executable! Remove the `-s` from the link command.